# How to aggregate on 2 levels, first by count and second a function f(count)?

Tags: r, aggregation

I have done a similar thing in SQL in the past, but I am new to R, and I apologise in advance if this is a basic question.

How would I aggregate data based on taking counts of 1 class first, then applying a function on those counts to aggregate it again?

Lets say my data is:

```
df<-data.frame(ID1=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), 
ID2=c(201,201,203,203,204,201,202,204,204,201,203,203,204,203))
```

first, I would aggregate ID2 by counts, to get a data frame that would look like:

```
df2<-data.frame(ID1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
ID2=c(201,203,204,201,202,204,201,203,204), 
counts=c(2,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1))
```

after this, I would apply a function to aggregate on ID1(it is basically the product of fraction of the counts. so for ID=1, it would be (2/5) * (2/5) * (1/5), for ID=2, it would be (1/4) * (1/4) * (2/4) and so on. So the final data frame would look like:

```
df3<-data.frame(ID1=c(1,2,3), f=c(0.032, 0.03125, 0.024))
```

How does one do multiple aggregations like this, and aggregations using a function like one does in SQL?

Comment: The code for `df` fails.

Comment: I missed a 2 in ID1, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this first by grouping `ID1` and `ID2`, count the number of rows, then `group_by` `ID1` and perform the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID1) %>%
  summarise(f = prod(count)/(sum(count) ^ n()))
```

Comment: Why `ungroup()` and then `group_by(ID1)` again? Successive `summarise` calls go one group deeper for every call right?  In this case it just means we can call summarise two times and forego the `ungroup() %>% group_by(ID1)`

Comment: @atomman I was not aware about that but it seems you are right. `df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  summarise(f = prod(count)/(sum(count) ^ n()))` gives the same result. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a compact way with `table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID1) %>% 
  summarise(n = {tbl <- table(ID2); prod(tbl)/(sum(tbl)^length(tbl))})
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    ID1      n
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 0.032 
#2     2 0.0312
#3     3 0.024
```

---

Another option would be

```
library(matrixStats)
tbl <- table(df)
rowProds(na_if(tbl, 0), na.rm = TRUE)/rowSums(tbl)^rowSums(tbl!= 0)
#    1       2       3 
# 0.03200 0.03125 0.02400
```

Comment: the first method works perfectly, I just dont understand how the code itself works. How do the curly braces work? Theyre clearly what allowed you to do it in this way. My biggest issue with coding tends to be how inefficient my code is.

Comment: @ArjunMohan  IN the first method, we group by 'ID1', then get the frequency of 'ID2' with `table`.  Using that 'tbl' (with inthe `{}` - to extract the object within the block), do the calculation

Comment: so if I use the curly braces at the end, i just ensure the last line is some object, and not `name<-object` right? i can use this syntax any way i want?